# Lose events with ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new in Html/Css/Js and I have the following problem: I want to create a list of a certain component. I've already created the componentA (works perfecly) and now, in componentB I want to add with ng-include a specific number of componentsA but it seems to loose my ng-click event.

Can anybody help me ?

Later edit:

This is a piece of componentA:
HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container"> 
    <p   id="details"   class="details"   ng-show="!pressed" ng-click="Expand();">DETAILS</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('componentA', [function () {

      return {
          templateUrl: 'componentA.html',
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: true,
          controller: function ($scope) {

              $scope.pressed = false;

              $scope.Expand = function() {

                  if ($scope.pressed === true) {
                      $scope.pressed = false;
                      document.getElementById("container").style.width = '550px';
                      document.getElementById("details").style.webkitAnimation = "fadein 3s";
                  }
                  else{
                      $scope.pressed = true;
                      document.getElementById("container").style.width="780px";
                  }
              };
          }
      };
  }]);
```

In ComponentB, i'm trying to add some components A like this:

```
<div ng-include="'componentA.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'componentA.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'componentA.html'"></div>
```

it shows the components A, respect all the things from my css file, but nothing from my js file.

Comment: please post code - see [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please show us some of your code, otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: please post code or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I posted some of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created an attribute directive - so there is no reason to use ng-include (it will just insert the template, not the logic).

```
<div component-a></div>
```

Secondly, it is bad practice to manipulate the DOM through the controller. It seems that in this case it makes more sense to use the ngClass directive in your template instead of changing the styles in the controller.